# OpenOffice Calc merge cells without formatting?

Tags: date, datetime, time, openoffice-calc

Is it possible to merge cells without formatting in OpenOffice Calc?

I have:

```
    A                   B
2012-03-12          23:00:00
2013-02-12          23:00:00
2012-03-12          23:00:00
```

Etc

In Cell C I have formula `=A2 & " " & B2` which returns `41123 0.95833333333`

I need it to return `2012-03-12 23:00:00` but it refuses to do so, even when I set the cell to text. I can't set A or B to text because it messes them up and I have hundreds of cells to merge to rewriting them is not an option as well.

Is it possible to set a formula just to say copy it exactly as it appears regardless of formatting and print it in cell c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging date/time values is much easier: just **sum both values** and **format the result as date/time**:

[image]

This works because date / time values are internally stored as numbers / fractions. Thus, you can apply arithmetical operations on the "raw" numbers.

Comment: Oh...A2 + B2 instead of A2 & B2. Got it for future reference. I actually jumped over to using Mac Numbers and it did what I want by default with my formula. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Calculating the sum works only with date/time values, since OOo stores them internally as numbers. With strings, concatenating the parts should work fine.